# Why is this retruning itiems that are not "SHOP"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select pnm.pnm_auto_key, pnm.pn, whs.warehouse_code, pnm.loc_auto_key   
      from parts_master pnm join warehouse whs on pnm.whs_auto_key = whs.whs_auto_key
                            
     where whs.warehouse_code = 'SHOP' 
          pnm.loc_auto_key = '39' 
           or pnm.loc_auto_key = '14'
```

Thank you.

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `OR` you misused. Should have probably been

```
where whs.warehouse_code = 'SHOP'
  and (   pnm.loc_auto_key = '39'
       or pnm.loc_auto_key = '14'
      )
```

Or, why not

```
where whs.warehouse_code = 'SHOP'
  and pnm.loc_auto_key in ('14', '39')
```

Comment: Just must have had a syntax snag.

Comment: Select pnm.pnm_auto_key, pnm.pn, whs.warehouse_code, pnm.loc_auto_key   
      from parts_master pnm join warehouse whs on pnm.whs_auto_key = whs.whs_auto_key
                            
     where whs.warehouse_code = 'SHOP' and
          pnm.loc_auto_key ( pnm.loc_auto_key <> '39' or
                             pnm.loc_auto_key <> '26' or
                             pnm.loc_auto_key <> '14' )

Comment: @Jeff. It doesn't. `pnm.loc_auto_key <> '39' or pnm.loc_auto_key <> '26'` is true for every number including 39 and 26. Just think about it. And why do you use quotes on numbers?

Comment: Hmmm. <> Does not equal.  I want the find for all number not equal to 39, 26, and 14.  I thought I had to use the single quotes.

Comment: @Jeff: Just try it. (26 <> 39) or (26 <> 26) is true, because 26 <> 39. But you want 26 to be false, so it gets excluded from your results. You want `AND`: (26 <> 39) and (26 <> 26) is false, because 26 = 26. And as shown, it is much easier to work with an `IN` clause: `pnm.loc_auto_key NOT IN (39, 26, 14)`.

Comment: It is a LOT easier but 39, 26, and 14, returned with the NOT IN.  Just not sure how to make if them false.

Comment: Went to high in the results.  Works like a charm,  Thanks Thorston.